# java accidential implicit interface implementation

Tags: java, inheritance, compiler-construction, polymorphism

Recently came across an interesting feature, which, though, can result in a unexpected output of Eclipse "add unimplemented methods" feature. What is the "googl-able" name of the language concept behind this "occasional implicit implementation"?

I wouldn't expect the code below to compile but it did and is working

```
interface CallmeIfc {
  public void callme();
}

class CallmeCode {
  public void callme() {
    // implementation  
  }
}

class CallmeImpl extends CallmeCode implements CallmeIfc {
  // empty class body
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  CallmeIfc me = (CallmeIfc) new CallmeImpl();
  me.callme(); // calls CallmeCode.callme()
}
```

Comment: Um... inheritance? Virtual function tables?

Comment: Your `CallMeImpl` implements `public void callme()` via inheriting it from `CallMeCode`. That's all, there's no special name for it.

Comment: @Joonas Pulakka - I got the name for it, "subcontracting", Impl is exactly like an agency, serves a client(interface) by a  contractor(super class) without letting them know each other :)

Comment: @OrangeDog - yes, right, but havily misused

Comment: @bobah - Not really, that's what it's designed to do.

Comment: OrangeDog - see my last comment to Oliver's answer

Comment: Yes, it is rather surprising that the overriding method need not be defined in a subtype of the method it overrides, making it possible that the overriding method does not know that or which method it overrides - and how is it supposed to satisfy the "inherited" contract then?

Comment: OK, this thing has a name after all -- a [Mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this looks like a compiler bug to me: The Java Language Specification [writes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.8.1):

> An instance method `m1` declared in a
>   class `C` overrides another instance
>   method, `m2`, declared in class `A` iff
>   all of the following are true:
>
> - `C` is a subclass of `A`.
> - The signature of `m1` is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of `m2`.
> - Either
>
>   - `m2` is public, protected or declared with default access in the same package as `C`, or
>   - `m1` overrides a method `m3`, `m3` distinct from `m1`, `m3` distinct from `m2`, such that `m3` overrides `m2`.

In your case, the first condition is not satisfied: The method `callme` is declared in class `CallMeCode`, which is not a subtype of `CallmeIfc`.

**Edit**: Bobah is right, the Spec distinguishes between implementing and overriding. In fact, it actually [mandates](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.5) the observed behaviour:

> Unless the class being declared is
>   abstract, the declarations of all the
>   method members of each direct
>   superinterface must be implemented
>   either by a declaration in this class
>   or by an existing method declaration
>   inherited from the direct superclass,
>   because a class that is not abstract
>   is not permitted to have abstract
>   methods

The Spec does not explain why.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if a class implementing an interface is a "subclass" of that interface and the implementation of an interface method is "overriding". So what we observe can be a valid compiler behavior, a bit unusual though.

Answer (score 2):

In CallmeImpl, the public callme() method is inherited from CallmeCode, so CallmeImpl respects the contract defined in the CallmeIfc.

Then, in your main() method, polymorphism allows you to assign a subclass instance (CallmeImpl) to a superclass or superinterface reference - in this particular case, the "me" reference, of type CallmeIfc (you have a typo here, BTW).

Comment: Which part of my question have you answered?

Comment: Well, I fail to see what you find "unexpected" in this code and its behavior. It's very standart OO design. So I tried to explain the OO concepts making it work. Here the "googleable terms" are inheritance and polymorphism.

If you have a more precise question, I'll be glad to try to answer it.

Comment: I am not sure that interface and implementing code being not on the same root-leaf path in the inheritance tree is "very standart OO design". When I created a question I expected an answer like "ah! this is easy, it's called xxx, works like yyy, that's why it's possible in Java unlike C++".

Comment: AH, I see. Looks like the C++ implementation is a restriction of a more general OO supported by Java, where inheritance can occur between classes/interfaces in different packages.

Answer (score 1):

Although CallmeCode class doesn't implement the CallmeIfc interface, it provides the necessary implementation. It is as if class CallmeCode implements the interface. It would have worked also with this code:

```
interface CallmeIfc {
    public void callme();
}

class CallmeCode implements CallmeIfc {
    public void callme() {
      // implementation  
    }
}

class CallmeImpl extends CallmeCode implements CallmeIfc {
   // empty class body
}
```

In your case this is fine because class CallmeCode has a method callme. If the method would have been named different it wouldn't compile.